# Decrease row height in tabularray

Tags: tables, height, tabularray

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray, xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{
columns={3em, c, colsep=2pt},
rows={3em, m, rowsep=2pt},
row{2,3} = {ht=0pt, abovesep=0pt, belowsep=0pt},
column{1,2} = {wd=0.2em},
vline{1} = {1-Z}{red,solid},
vline{2} = {1-2}{solid},
vline{3,5} = {1,4}{solid} 
}
\cline{3-4}
&& text 1 & text 2 \\   
\cline{3-4}
&&& \\
\cline{2-4}
&&& \\
\cline{3-4}
&& text 3 & text 4\\
\cline{3-4}
\end{tblr}  
    
\end{document}
```

Red line here is just to show left border of table.

One can change the distance from vertical line (of right angle) to the table by varying width of dummy columns 1 and 2: `column{1,2}={wd=0.2em}`. I have already set the height and separations of dummy rows 2 and 3 both to zero (`row{2,3}={ht=0pt, abovesep=0pt, belowsep=0pt}`), but I want to more decrease the vertical distance from horizontal line (of right angle) to the nearby rows, i.e. make this distance about the same as horizontal one (`0.2em` here). So, how to minimize the row height in tabularray?

Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In `tabular` enviroment, every cell has minimal vertical space from `\strut` command whose size is specified by `\arraystretch` parameter.

The same is true for `tblr` environment, while the difference is that we use `stretch` option here. You can remove the strut by setting `stretch=0`.

Setting `\arraystretch=0` will break the alignment in `tabular` environment but setting `stretch=0` doesn't break the alignment in `tblr` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray, xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{
  columns={3em, c, colsep=2pt},
  rows={3em, m, rowsep=2pt},
  row{2,3} = {0.2em},
  column{1,2} = {0.2em},
  vline{1} = {red,solid},
  vline{2} = {1-2}{solid},
  vline{3,5} = {1,4}{solid},
  stretch = 0,
}
\cline{3-4}
&& text 1 & text 2 \\   
\cline{3-4}
&&& \\
\cline{2-4}
&&& \\
\cline{3-4}
&& text 3 & text 4\\
\cline{3-4}
\end{tblr} 
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much!