# tabularray: Why do the cells not seem vertically centered?

Tags: tables, tabularray

For the following, why does it seem to me that the numbers are a bit **above** where they should be at the very exact vertical center?

On the other hand, what content should be written that is supposed to have equal spaces above and below it to make sure the vertical centering is working right?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tblr}
        {
            rows = {m},
            rulesep=0pt,
            width = 0.5\linewidth,
            colspec = {X X}, 
            row{odd} = {blue!15}, 
            row{even} = {gray!15},       
            rowhead = 1,
            row{1} = {red!20},
        }
        \toprule[1.5pt]
        0  &   2  \\
        TEXT  &   4  \\
        8  &   6  \\
        text  &   8  \\
        \bottomrule[1.5pt]
    \end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use `stretch=0` to remove the strut. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/611976/decrease-row-height-in-tabularray/611994#611994

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Just a guess.
- The spacing is correct for content that goes below the baseline, like the lower case "g".
- See, for example, Werner's answer, [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121627).

[image]

---

> [image]
>
> [Taken from here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121627)